# Counting multiple specific value in the same mysql request

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT(* WHERE media_id = 1) as count_1, 
COUNT(* WHERE media_id = 2) as count_2 
WHERE user_id = 1
```

or do I have to make separate queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional sum something as

```
select
sum(media_id = 1) as count_1,
sum(media_id = 2) as count_2 
from table_name
where user_id = 1;
```

Note that using aggregate function does not make sense with `select *`

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's possible.

Try this for example:

```
select 
(select count(*) from TableA where 1=1) as totalA,
(select count(*) from TableB where 1=1) as totalB,
(select count(*) from TableC where 1=1) as totalc
```